# Changing a string in a subroutine in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

```
def modify(text):
    text = text[:1] + 'Z' + text[2:]
    return

text = 'abcdefg'
modify(text)
print text
```

This does not change the string. What is the best way to make such changes?

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow. Post what you are expecting also.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, you *can't* change them in a function and see the change outside the function.

The proper way to do this is to return the modified string and reassign it where it was called.

```
def modify(text):
    text = text[:1] + 'Z' + text[2:]
    return text

text = 'abcdefg'
text = modify(text)
print text
```

Comment: I dont' think this is about immutable strings.  I think the issue is that the OP thinks that assignment to a name that has been passed as an argument affects the calling scope.  You offer the correct solution, but the incorrect diagnosis.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski in that case they should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: Yes, that addresses it perfectly.  Matter of fact, I'm closing this question in favor of that one.

Answer (score 1):

You must `return` the modified text from your `modify` function, otherwise, your modification won't take any effect:

```
def modify(text):
    text = text[:1] + 'Z' + text[2:]
    return text
```

And since text inside `modify` function is a `local` variable, the modification won't affect the `global` `text` variable (which you passed to `modify` function) until you assign it:

`text = modify(text)`